# Empty ArrayList when opening a new jFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jframe

I am creating a subnetmanager which could work easily inside a company. Now I have a first window where I can add new subnets - with the 'add subnet' button. Which takes you through a few steps. Giving in the subnetname, network address and subnetmask.

Once added the program returns to this same starting window, but with the subnet added to the jList. 
[image: Homepage Subnet Manager]

Now I am trying to open a second jFrame which opens the selected subnet out of the JList from the overview page. There I have a problem with putting the previous entered values inside the jTextFields of the second jFrame. It stays empty and after going through debug mode, I saw that my ArrayList is empty again after opening the second jFrame.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>       at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)

[image: JFrame selected Subnet]

Now the two GUI's are both seperate java files (SubnetManager.java & SubnetGUI.java). Which is helped by a class Subnet(.java) which contains the logical methodes.

Code SubnetManager.java:

```
Subnet n = new Subnet();
private DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
private int getal;

/**
 * Creates new form SubnetManager
 */
public SubnetManager() {
    initComponents();
}    

/**
 * Opens up the jFrame of SubnetGUI.java with the values of the selected jList value.
 * 
 * @param evt Clickevent 'Change' Button
 */
private void jButtonChangeSubnetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    //integer 'getal' gets the index of the selected jList value
    getal = jListSubnet.getSelectedIndex();

    //closes jFrame from SubnetManagerGUI
    this.setVisible(false);

    //Opens up the jFrame from SubnetGUI
    SubnetGUI s = new SubnetGUI();
    s.setVisible(true);
}                                                   

/**
 * Gettermethod which provides the index of the selected JList value.
 * 
 * @return index of selected JList value
 */
public int getGetal() {
    return this.getal;
}
```

Code SubnetGUI.java:

```
private SubnetManager n = new SubnetManager();
private Subnet s = new Subnet();
private String getal2;

/**
 * Creates new form Subnet
 */
public SubnetGUI() {
    initComponents();
    this.getal2 = s.naamSubnet.get(n.getGetal());
}
```

Initialing jTextField of selected subnet (name) - SubnetGUI.java:
[image: SubnetGUI initizialing jTextFieldName]

Code logical class Subnet.java:

```
public class Subnet {
private String naam, netwerkadres, subnetmask;

//ArrayList which saves the names of the Subnets
public final ArrayList<String> naamSubnet = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public Subnet() {

}

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param naam name of subnet
 * @param netwerkadres network address of subnet
 * @param subnetmask subnetmask of subnet
 */
public Subnet(String naam, String netwerkadres, String subnetmask) {
    this.naam = naam;
    this.netwerkadres = netwerkadres;
    this.subnetmask = subnetmask;
}

/**
 * Method to add names of subnets to the ArrayList naamSubnet.
 * 
 * @param antwoord name provided in SubnetManager GUI
 */
public void naamSubnet(String antwoord) {
    naamSubnet.add(antwoord);
}
```

}

Now my question is, how it's possible for the ArrayList to be empty when the second jFrame gets opened? Does the program reset and do I need to open up a new jFrame within the SubnetManager.java class? Or am I overseeing the problem?

Comment: For real help, consider posting real [mcve] code. Please read the link. As a side recommendation, a GUI should have one and only one JFrame.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've filtered out alot of code already before posting. Just wanted to make sure the communication between the classes is clear. Last time I've got the reaction to put more of my code online. And thank you for the info about the jFrame.

Comment: Please read or reread the link I've given you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem. At the lines:

```
private SubnetManager n = new SubnetManager();
private Subnet s = new Subnet();
```

Slibbed through my mind that when you use "new" it creates a new object. So I fixed it by adding gettermethod in my logical class Subnet.java and deleting those two lines.